# How to create a file in the terminal of VSC?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, shortcut

I know how to create a folder in the terminal of vsc `mkdir NameOfFolder`, but how to create a file in the terminal?

Comment: use `touch filename`

Comment: How you create a new file depends on which shell you are running in the terminal, not the IDE that is providing the terminal.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> to open the terminal in Visual Studio Code.

`echo > "File.txt"` to create a new `.txt` file in the current directory.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use:

> code filename.filetype

This also works with directories

> code app/program.py

This wil open the new file in te editor (if the filetype allows it) and then you can just save it.

Answer (score 1):

Once you are in the desired directory in VSCode terminal, use `touch file_name.file_extension` Eg: `touch README.md`. It works just like LINUX.

Answer (score 1):

ni filename.txt

This worked for me on Windows VSC.

Comment: what does the "ni" stand for?

Comment: ni stands for "New Item"

Answer (score 1):

$ touch example.py (if using bash)

> echo "# This is an example PowerShell script" > example.py (if using PowerShell)

Answer (score 0):

On Windows Powershell, use `New-Item -Path . -Name "testfile1.txt"`. This  creates a text file that is named testfile1.txt. You can also check out the [Microsoft website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item?view=powershell-7.3) for more information.

Answer (score -1):

Just type square bracket ">" and name in the bash terminal of VScode:

```
> fileName.txt
```

Answer (score -2):

you can also use : ni filename.thx